# PFQuery, hasCachedResult() always retuning false?

Tags: ios, caching, parse-platform, pfquery

Currently trying to just check if the query has cached inside PFQueryTableViewcontroller, using a simple if statement but regardless it keeps returning false, even when i turn internet off and can access page through cache.

```
 var query = PFQuery(className: "Tasks")
     var  isInCache:Bool = query.hasCachedResult()
            println(isInCache)
 query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheElseNetwork
        return query
```

Trying to just simply us an if statement checking internet and and if there is a cache. If anyone has any workarounds this would be really helpful been on this a while now

Comment: I have the same problem, I would be very curious to know if anyone has ever gotten this thing to work as advertised?